# Swift draw rectangle

Tags: swift, core-graphics

I am trying to draw a rectangle on touch. So far I have two pieces of code, the fist one is a method that currently draws a circle, the 2nd piece of code adds the shape to view, how do I draw a rectangle instead?

```
func drawRectangle() {
    // Get the Graphics Context
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Set the rectangle outerline-width
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0);

    // Set the rectangle outerline-colour
    UIColor.redColor().set()

    // Create Rectangle

    CGContextAddArc(context, (frame.size.width)/2, frame.size.height/2, (frame.size.width - 10)/2, 0.0, CGFloat(M_PI * 2.0), 1)

    // Draw
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    let rectangleCenter = touches.first!.locationInView(view)

    let rectangleWidth = CGFloat(50)
    let rectangleHeight = rectangleWidth

    // Create a new rectangleView
    let rectangleView = Annotations(frame: CGRectMake(rectangleCenter.x, rectangleCenter.y, rectangleWidth, rectangleHeight), shape: 1)

    view.addSubview(rectangleView)  
}
```

I have tried the following:

```
// Create Rectangle
        CGContextAddRect(context, CGRectMake((frame.size.width)/2, frame.size.height/2, 40, 40));
```

it creates part of the top left of the rectangle with the line on top and a line down the left. How do I adjust this to be a full rectangle?

Comment: If you look up CGContextAddArc in the  CGContext reference then CGContextAddRect is not far away ... :)

Comment: Hi Martin R, I tried CGContextAddRect, it gives me half of a rectangle

Comment: Then you create the wrong rectangle. The first two parameters of CGRectMake  are the origin (upper-left corner), not the midpoint.

Comment: Martin R can I see an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by doing the following:

increase the width and height here:

```
let rectangleWidth = CGFloat(100)
let rectangleHeight = rectangleWidth
```

and my rectangle method

```
func drawRectangle()
    {
        // Get the Graphics Context
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

        // Set the rectangle outerline-width
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0);

        // Set the rectangle outerline-colour
        UIColor.redColor().set()

        // Create Rectangle
        CGContextAddRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100));

        // Draw
        CGContextStrokePath(context);

    }
```

## for **swift 4.2** :

this code uses for swift 4.2

```
func drawRectangle()
{
    // Get the Graphics Context
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    // Set the rectangle outerline-width
    context?.setLineWidth( 5.0)

    // Set the rectangle outerline-colour
    UIColor.red.set()

    // Create Rectangle
    context?.addRect( CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))

    // Draw
    context?.strokePath()

}
```

Comment: Just a comment, I couldn't see the rect until I called `drawRectangle()` in `draw(_:)` method of `UIView`, see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622529-draw.